# Drupal 7: Trying to override the main menu, can it be done?

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to make it so that the Main Menu in Drupal 7 is printed in HTML like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#" >Home<span>Introduction</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Features<span>The feature tour</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Pricing<span>Our fee made clear</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Support<span>Help when needed</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Blog<span>Stay informed</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Inside the span tags I would like to print the description if there is one for the menu link item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the various theme functions that generate your menus. http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/theme_menu